# gradle logging shows messages only when I use lifecycle

Tags: gradle

I am trying to display logger messages like this

```
def myMethod(Project proj, msg) {
   proj.logger.info msg
}
```

However it shows nothing when I invoke `myMethod`.
However when I use `lifecycle` instead of `info` - it works fine and displays message properly

```
def myMethod(Project proj, msg) {
   proj.logger.lifecycle msg
}
```

What is wrong? What is needed to be configured in order to make `info` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run gradle with `-i` switch to get info statements, `-d` when debug is used.

Lifecycle is printed always unless `-q` switch is passed.

You can do it programmatically with the following piece of code:

```
logging.setLevel(LogLevel.INFO)
logger.info('lol')
```

When `gradle` is run *lol* will be printed out without `-i` switch.

Comment: Is there a way to do that programmatically? Because `-i` for example will add some additional messages that I do not need.

Comment: @user1432980, yes it's possible. See the updated answer.